# Running a binary executable as an auto-starting service on Gentoo

Tags: linux, automation, service, gentoo

I have a Gentoo box on Linode and couldn't get to install [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) thorough Portage, so I'm running the static binary I downloaded from the website.

---

How do I make it run as a service, and how do I add it to the auto-start list so it comes back up when the system is rebooted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Gentoo for a while, but I would just copy one of the simpler scripts from /etc/init.d and adjust it to run MongoDB. That should be a trivial task

Answer (score 0):

rc-update add SERVICE default

or

echo "/opt/foo/service" >> /etc/conf.d/local.start

Comment: My problem was that I didn't have the init script to run rc-update against.